# Combine two resulting rows in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have the follow query:

```
select user_id from user_tags
where user_id = 3086533
```

which outputs:

[image]

Essentially, I want to be able to take this query, and change it to only include the user_id if both the name "master_sbx" and "phonePicked"appear.

So instead of writing a query of:

```
select user_id from user_tags
where user_id = 3086533
```

with an output of:

[image]

I would like to add the clause of only including user_id of only ids that have both "master_sbx" and "phonePicked" applied, so the output would just return

[image]

Hoping this makes sense. I'm not sure its actually possible in PostGreSQL but would love any feedback! It is piece of a larger query I am going to write.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want test a `user_id` whether it (at least) appears in a row with `name = 'master_sbx'` as well as in a row with `name = 'phonePicked'`.

There are *many* ways to do this. The best choice depends on information that is not in your question. One way would be with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM   user_tags
WHERE  user_id = 3086533
AND    name = 'master_sbx'
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM user_tags
   WHERE  user_id = 3086533
   AND    name = 'phonePicked'
   )
```

Another way with a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.user_id
FROM   user_tags u1
JOIN   user_tags u2 USING (user_id)
WHERE  u1.user_id = 3086533
AND    u1.name = 'master_sbx'
AND    u2.name = 'phonePicked';
```

`DISTINCT` is redundant if `(user_id, name)` is unique.

This can be treated as special case of [*relational division*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-division). We have assembled a whole arsenal of query techniques in this related answer:
[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)